# Can't change selected option in a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a select and I want it's selected option to change but I can't make it happen for some reason. This is the code that I have.

```
$("#ID option[value=grpValue]").prop('selected', 'selected').change();
```

If instead of using "grpValue" I type in the value manually for example value "3" it does work. But I want it to use grpValue.

So this for example does work.

```
$("#ID option[value=3]").prop('selected', 'selected').change();
```

What am I doing wrong in the first line?

Would appreciate the help, thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've already tried using `option[value='grpValue']`, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `grpValue` a variable? If so

```
$("#ID option[value="+grpValue+"]").prop('selected', 'selected').change();
```

will make the attribute selector do the work.

BTW, I think

```
$obj.prop('selected', true);
```

is the correct expression for `prop`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#sel option[value='c']").attr("selected",true);
  $("#sel option[value='c']").prop("selected",true);
});
```

```html
<html><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <select id="sel">
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
you can use any one from prop() or attr() method both of useful
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id_of_select').val('value_of_option_here');
```

Edit: To explain why the above code works. The first part:

Is the jQuery we use the following method to select an element by it's id, we could also select an element by it's class by simply changing the '#' to a '.'.

```
$('#id_of_select')
```

The statement following it refers to the value attribute that is attached to every input, select, textarea and button. The value is the string that is passed through when a form is submitted. For inputs this is the typed text, for selects it's the value of the selected option.

When we click an option in a select field, what we are actually doing is grabbing the value of the option and setting it as the selects value also, selects know what value is selected via the value, it can then grab the option text associated with this value. The code below (with a parameter) will set the value of the select field, in the same way it would if you were to click the option.

Note .val must have a parameter otherwise you are just asking jQuery what the value of the selected field is. With a value will set, without a value will get.

```
.val('value_of_option_here');
```

Hope this is a little more useful than my original answer, I've tried to break it down as much as possible though if it's a little confusing let me know.

Comment: @Alexander answer updated, hope this is a little more helpful.

Comment: Wow! Anton Chekhov said: "Brevity is the soul of wit" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Working example :

```js
$("#ID option[value='b']").prop('selected', 'selected').change();
// if value in variable just replace  $("#ID option[value="+valueInVar+"]")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ID" >
<option value = "a">a</option>
<option value = "b">b</option>
<option value = "c">c</option>
</select>
```